AppBar issues encountered during WinUI 3 development
I'm a complete newbie to WinUI 3 development and this is the problem I'm running into.
When my window is in focus, the minimize, maximize, and close buttons on the AppBar appear in a light style.
Click to view >> Light Style
When my window loses focus, it shows a black style.
Click to view >> Black Style
Because my App theme is in Light Mode, what I want is that the buttons on the AppBar of the window are always displayed in black.
In App.xmal I added RequestedTheme="Light", and my OS is in Dark Mode.
In this window's xaml code page, I added the following code:
 <Window.SystemBackdrop>
     <MicaBackdrop Kind="Base"/>
 </Window.SystemBackdrop>

In this window's xaml.cs code page, I added the following code in its Constructor:
public LoginWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = true; // Here here
 
    DO_SOMETHING();
}

Is these related to the problem I'm having?
I want that the buttons on the AppBar of the window are always displayed in black for my Application is in Light Mode.

Ah, you mean the title bar, not the AppBar, which is an actual WinAppSdk control.
In short, you need to respond to settings updates and update the title bar manually:
    // in the constructor
    settings = new UISettings();
    settings.ColorValuesChanged += Settings_ColorValuesChanged; // cannot use FrameworkElement.ActualThemeChanged event

    // in the event handler above
    dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
        TitleBarHelper.ApplySystemThemeToCaptionButtons();

And the TitleBarHelper class is here, curtesy of the WinUI3 Template Studio: https://github.com/microsoft/TemplateStudio/blob/main/code/TemplateStudioForWinUICs/Templates/Proj/Default/Param_ProjectName/Helpers/TitleBarHelper.cs

Thank you for answering this question! But it is still a little hard for me, a newbie in WinUI development, to understand. I plan to put this question aside and come back to it when I am more knowledgeable.

In the process of self-research, I found that WinUI 3 Gallery also has the same problem. If your operating system theme is dark (the application theme set in the system is also dark), then go to the settings of WinUI 3 Gallery, manually set WinUI 3 Gallery to light, and then close and restart WinUI 3 Gallery, the problem I encountered will be reproduced on WinUI 3 Gallery.
So I think this may be a bug in WinUI 3 implementation. If you agree with me, please help me submit this bug to Microsoft. As a newbie, I can't judge whether this is really a bug.

Anyway, thank you very much for answering this question for me!

It's not a bug, it's a limitation -- WinUI windows are just Win32 windows. Do as above and you'll have your title bar buttons switching themes correctly. If it helps you more, you can see the same thing implemented in one of my projects: https://github.com/myblindy/GrimBuilder2
